# Infinispan clustering is not working on EKS cluster

Tags: amazon-eks, infinispan

I deploy the infinispan cluster using these following code:
https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-helm-charts

On Minikube: Its working fine

When i run above command infinispan server got created and goes into cluster

on EKS : clustering is not happening
When i run above command infinispan server got created but NOT goes into cluster

helm lint ./infinispan-helm-charts
helm install -n qa infinispan-server ./infinispan-helm-charts

And then port forward to access

kubectl port-forward service/infinispan-server 11222:11222 -n qa

Answer (score 0):

EKS clustering works as expected with Infinispan 14.0.x, the issue here is that a no longer supported upstream version (10.1.x) was being deployed.

https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-helm-charts/issues/63